# pasting script to command line with indents

Tags: awk, indentation

When I try copying and pasting a portion of my script into command line, I get a bunch of file names and directories along with my actual code. For example if I copy and paste something very simple like:

```
awk '{
         if ($4=="YES")

         print $0

}' file
```

I get things like:

```
.java/ .history .pip/ .bash_history
```

printed on the command line. It has something to do with the indentations in my script, because if I copy and paste the script like:

```
awk '{

if ($4=="YES")

print $0

}'
```

I get no unwanted items pasted on the command line.

Has anyone experienceed this? I'm not sure if there is a particular way to indent code properly that I am not following?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the embedded tabs you are using for indentation being seen as tab-completion attempts. Not using tabs for indentation will prevent that problem from happening.

Comment: and this is an issue with your shell, it has absolutely nothing to do with awk. Having said that, on a completely different subject: your awk script can/should be reduced to just `awk '$4=="YES"' file` - all the rest of the code you wrote is extraneous and just duplicates the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you press Tab twice at a `bash` prompt, it will show you a list of the possible filename completions, even if it's a `>` prompt in the middle of a multiline single-quoted string. When you tell your terminal emulator to paste text, it enters each character as if you typed it, so you should expect the same result.

If an awk script is complicated enough to benefit from indentation, you should put it in a file and then run it from the file using the `-f` option

`awk -f filename`